# How to deal with a dog that barks at people when the owner is not present

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

I have two labrador retrievers, both very socialized and outgoing. I take them obedience trials and are fully trained. I am stuck because today my neighbor said one of my dogs barks at every person walking by or making noise. My neighbor said it isn't a anxiety bark just a loud annoy the neighbors kind. The neighbor also said it never happens when i'm home just when I leave for work, the dogs can come in and out of dog door and for some reason the one girl patrols the fence all day looking for someone to bark at. I am at a loss as to how to fix this since I am not around when she does this, and in my presence she will not do it. I of course could kennel her in the house or let her have free roam of the house she is housebroken, but I would like idea's to actually fix the problem. Any advice

Comment: Do you have any idea why she's doing this?  Boredom vs guarding?

Answer (score 0):

**My Experience:**

I have a [Pet Partners](https://petpartners.org/volunteer/our-therapy-animal-program/) B+ Lab/Beagle mix who is 12 years old. She is great is almost every situation. That being said, she barks in the house at nonsense. A movement out the window (we are on 2nd floor of a Chicago apartment, so nothing is really a threat) and she goes off.

They say to avoid breaking animals of instinctive behavior. "Don't try and train a raccoon not to wash its food" is a saying I hear in dog training.

For thousands of years, dog barking has been super helpful to people. Dogs have evolved to bark at perceived danger.

**My Advice:**

Don't fight the dog. If you can use a "close the blinds" and "turn up the music" approach, it might work better than "training" on this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options that work well.

**1. Ultrasonic Sound Emitter** ([Cheap Option](https://smile.amazon.com/PetSafe-Indoor-Ultrasonic-Control-Anti-Bark/dp/B00068R98C/ref=sr_1_7?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1521705415&sr=1-7&keywords=bark%20deterrent%20ultrasonic)) - $25

This is actually one of the most useful tools in your toolbox. It will make a harsh sound when the bark gets above a certain decibel level (customizable). The best part is that your neighbors can't hear it!

**2. Anti-bark collar** ([Cheap Option](https://smile.amazon.com/PetSafe-Anti-Bark-Training-Waterproof-Correction/dp/B0002C7FHC/ref=sr_1_6?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1521705494&sr=1-6&keywords=anti-bark%20collar)) - $30

These are great for dogs that just won't stop! A slight shock is all that is necessary to create the association with Bark = Bad.

Also check out this [resource](https://minihuskylovers.com/best-anti-barking-devices/)!

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

Once your dog learns not to bark during PERCEIVED DANGER, it will be incredibly hard to get them to learn how to bark again when there is ACTUAL DANGER. It might be worthwhile to teach your dog something called "Positive Aggression", which means how to understand when there is ACTUALLY DANGER and to react correctly for this danger. This is how police and military dogs are trained. You want your dog to be a protector, as well as a fun pet. Since they are considered deadly weapons when they successfully attack an individual (and are 99.99% genetically equivalent to wolves), you should train your dog to be a weapon that is only fired toward enemies.